# Can you make a interferometer with circularly polarized light?

Tags: optics, waves, interference, polarization

If I make a Michelson interferometer with circularly polarized light, does the path difference make any difference in the brightness of the resulting beam?

I do understand that circularly polarized beams do interfere in some form, I just want to know if there is any change in the brightness.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to work it out but as a hint. You have to look at the interfering term that is
$$I_{12}=2\langle  \mathbf{E}_1\cdot \mathbf{E}_2\rangle $$
Recall
$$\mathbf{E}^2=\mathbf{E}_1^2+\mathbf{E}_2^2+2  \mathbf{E}_1\cdot \mathbf{E}_2$$
Taking the averages
$$I=\langle \mathbf{E}_1^2\rangle+\langle \mathbf{E}_2^2\rangle+2\langle  \mathbf{E}_1\cdot \mathbf{E}_2\rangle $$
or
$$I=I_1+I_2+I_{12}$$
Now you can proceed!